# Get json key name from json.javax.JsonObject?

Tags: java, json

Suppose I have a JsonObject from [javax](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html) named jsonObject, which looks like this: `{"key":"value"}`

How can I get the key name `key`?

I only find methods like `getJsonString` to get the key value `value`, but not the name of the key itself.

Background:

I have a Json Array, which contains key-value pairs. I want to know the name of the key on a specific index `i`.

Example:

`[{"key1":"value0"},{"key1":"value1"},{"key2","value2"}]`

`key1` here is a success, `key2` is a fail and has to be checked.

Comment: One would guess you get the `entrySet` or `keySet` and iterate through it.  In the above example each of the three objects in the array has only one key, so "iterating" is no big burden.

Comment: (Note that JsonObject implements the Map interface, and Map has all sorts of useful functions.)

Comment: (And note that, before asking a question of this sort, you should visit the documentation for the class and check not only the methods directly implemented by the class but any that are "inherited".)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JsonObject` implements `Map<String, JsonValue>`.  You can call `jsonObject.keySet()` to access the keys, or call `jsonObject.entrySet()` to get a complete view of the object including both keys and values.

```
for (String key: jsonObject.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(key);
}
```

In the context of the problem you described, it sounds like you'll want to validate that each array element contains an object with exactly one key-value pair.  Perhaps something like this:

```
Set<Map.Entry<String, JsonValue>> kvPairs = jsonObject.entrySet();
if (kvPairs.size() == 1) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, JsonValue> kvPair: kvPairs) {
        if (kvPair.getKey().equals("key1")) {
            // success
        } else {
            // error handling
        }
    }
} else {
    // error handling
}
```